# replace \\ to \ when using @ symbol

Tags: c#, replace

Issue with replacing text...username is 'JoelFarrell'

```
userName = @"WILD\" + userName; // returns "WILD\\JoelFarrell"

    I only want "WILD\JoelFarrell" so ive tried to replace it

    userName = userName.Replace("\\", @"\");//this does not work

    userIdInDNNUsersTable = DbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Username == userName).Count();//returns 0 results because it is searching for 'WILD\\JoelFarrell' where as if it was searching for 'WILD\JoelFarrell' I would get what I am looking for
```

Any one have any ideas? thanks for any replies

If i test it in quick watch and change `userName = "WILDFIRE\JoelFarrel"` it says unrecognized rewscapce sequece. but if I search SQL for the record in the db `

```
select * FROM [Dot].[dbo].[Users]
  where username LIKE '%WILDFIRE\JoelFarrell%'`
```

returns the result I am looking. So how do I get this result in code?

Comment: You are looking at the debug output of that variable. This is (the double backslashes) how the VS shows you a variable that contains a _single_ backslash to differentiate from a variable that contains an escaped character (a special character like the newline represented by a \n)

Comment: Asked 1 million  times. No one uses google anymore.

Comment: You are searching for `WILD\...` in the C# yet `WILDFIRE\...` in the SQL. Which is right?

Answer (score 2):

Actually

```
userName = @"WILD\" + userName; // returns "WILD\\JoelFarrell"
```

Returns

```
WILD\JoelFarrell
```

Its just that the debugger is displaying it as `\\` (very unhelpfully IMHO)

Comment: then why is the result returning 0 when I can see its in the DB

Comment: thats a different question. Could be all sorts of reasons

Comment: becase \J is an escaped character with no specific meaning. Do not try to remove the apparent double backslash

Comment: @Steve \J has nothing to do with it. Who would be interpreing \j as anything. But you are correct about the uselessness of the replace, Since there are no `\\\` there is actually doesnt do anything

Comment: my guess is probably case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at userName in the debugger, you're seeing the escaped version. Hit the magnifying glass beside the watch or tooltip. That will give you the non-escaped version.